# nodejs list only shows items after refresh

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a list thats nested inside a list, I made it with NodeJS, Express, EJS and MongoDB.
creating the first list works, however when creating items in the second list, they only appear after I refresh the website or create another item (creating an item automatically refreshes and site), I have struggled with this bug for a few day now, please dont laugh at me if its something stupid I am fairly new and this is my first real project.

```
route for the custom list
```

app.route("/BucketList/:customListID")
.get(function (req, res) {

```
    previousRoute = "/BucketList";
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        loggedIn = true;
        const customListID = req.params.customListID;
        const customListName = req.params.customListName
        Country.findOne({ _id: customListID }, function (err, foundList) {
            if (!err) {
                if (!foundList) {
                    res.redirect("/BucketList")
                } else {
                    foundList.save();
                    res.render("list", { customListID: customListID, customListName: customListName, customListCode: foundList.code, newListItems: foundList.items });
                }


            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }

        })
    } else {
        loggedIn = false;
        res.redirect("/login");
    }


})
.post(function (req, res) {
    const customListID = req.params.customListID;
    const customListName = req.params.customListName;
    const itemName = req.body.newItem;

    const item = new Item({
        name: itemName
    });

    Country.findOne({ _id: customListID }, function (err, foundList) {
        foundList.items.push(item);
        foundList.save();
        res.redirect("/BucketList/" + customListID);


    });

})
```

```
  <section class="vh-100" style="background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);">
        <div class="container py-5">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                <div class="col col-xl-10">
                    <div class="card" style="border-radius: 15px;">
                        <div class="card-body p-5">

                            <form class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-4"
                                action="/BucketList/<%=customListID%>" method="post">
                                <div class="form-outline flex-fill">
                                    <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="newItem"
                                        placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ms-2" name="list"
                                    value="<%= customListID %>">Add</button>
                            </form>
                            <% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
                                <ul class="list-group mb-0">
                                    <li
                                        class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center border-start-0 border-top-0 border-end-0 border-bottom rounded-0 mb-2">
                                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                            <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value=""
                                                aria-label="..." />
                                            <%=item.name%>
                                        </div>
                                        <form action="/deleteItem" method="post">
                                            <button type="submit" id="item-remove-button" title="Remove item"
                                                name="itemDeleteButton" value="<%= item._id %>"
                                                onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-times text-primary"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="listID" value="<%= customListID %>"></input>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <% }) %>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```